# Unable to make Isotope Filter/Sort Posts in WP

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loops, jquery

I am working on a site and I am trying to use Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html) to filter/sort posts on my taxonomy page. However for some reason I am unable to make it work regardless of what I do. I need some urgent help with this. Here is what my coding looks like - First I have this in my themes functions.php to generate the list of categories

```
function isotope_categories() {

        $terms = get_terms('videoscategory');

        $html = '<ul class="filters option-set" data-option-key="filter">';
        $html .= '<li><a href="#" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All items</a></li>';

        foreach ($terms as $term) {


            $html .= "<li><a href='#filter' data-filter='.boxes {$term->name}'>{$term->name}</a></li>";   
        }

        $html .= '</ul>';

        echo $html;
    }
```

Then on my taxonomy page I call it like so -

```
<nav id="options" class="option-set filter" data-option-key="filter">                       
    <?php isotope_categories() ?>
</nav>
```

The category links are generated, but they do not function like they are suppose to. This is my loop for the page -

```
<div id="content">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


 <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'videoscategory' ); ?>


<div class="boxes <?php foreach( $terms as $term ) echo ' ' . $term->name; ?>" style="width:100%; float:left; border-top:1px solid #ccc; margin-top:10px;">

// MY POST CONTENT AND DIVS

</div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
} ?>
</div>
```

And the js under it -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var mycontainer = jQuery('#content');
     mycontainer.isotope({
     itemSelector: '.boxes'
     });

   // filter items when filter link is clicked
jQuery('#options a').click(function(){
  var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
  mycontainer.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;  
  });

});
 </script>
```

I can not get it to work at all though, I've tried a few ways to get it to work but I guess I'm missing something or just doing it all wrong. What do I have to fix or change so that the filtering works??

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

By using the chrome debug console I was able to see this error - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isotope'  - Im not sure what it means though.

Comment: This question should be moved to Stack Overflow and tagged with jquery-isotope.  Your much more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: A link to what? The site? If so I am unable to because it is for a client and still undone. Is there any other info I can provide that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to get it to work and filter, except there are a few more things I have to work out to get it working the way I want. As far as the functionality of it though, I did manage to get it to work. In case anyone else is interested - here's what I did

1. First I went through my themes functions.php and my header to make sure the latest jquery was included and the correct scripts included, I also made sure it wasn't included multiple times and they were in the right order (jquery script first then isotope script.)

   `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/lib/jquery.isotope.min.js'></script>`
2. Next I made sure the CSS for isotope was in my style sheet.

   ```
   .isotope-item {
     z-index: 2;
   }

   .isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
     pointer-events: none;
     z-index: 1;
   }

   .isotope,
   .isotope .isotope-item {
     /* change duration value to whatever you like */
     -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
             transition-duration: 0.8s;
   }

   .isotope {
     -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
        -moz-transition-property: height, width;
             transition-property: height, width;
   }

   .isotope .isotope-item {
     -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
        -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
             transition-property:         transform, opacity;
   }
   ```
3. After that I edited the code in my functions for the filter list ( you can see the original in my question )

   ```
       function isotope_categories() {

       $terms = get_terms('videoscategory');

       $html = '<ul id="options">';
       $html .= '<li><a href="#" data-option-value="*" data-filter="*" class="selected">All items</a></li>';

       foreach ($terms as $term) {


           $html .= "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.{$term->slug}' class='current'>{$term->name}</a></li>";   
       }

       $html .= '</ul>';

       echo $html;
   }
   ```
4. Next I altered my coding for my loop -

   ```
      <div id="content" style="width: 94%;">
      <div id="isocontent">
      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'videoscategory' ); ?>

      <div class="box<?php foreach( $terms as $term ) echo ' ' . $term->slug; ?>" style="width:100%; float:left; border-top:1px solid #ccc; margin-top:10px;">

      //MY DIVS AND CONTENT

      </div>

      <?php endwhile; else: ?>

      <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>

      <?php endif; ?>
      <div style="position:absolute;">
      <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
   pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
      } ?>
      </div></div></div>
   ```
5. Then I edited the javascript code under it -

   ```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var mycontainer = $('#isocontent');
    mycontainer.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.box'
    });

      // filter items when filter link is clicked
      $('#options a').click(function(){
      var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
      mycontainer.isotope({ filter: selector });
      return false;  
      });

      });
      </script>
   ```

After doing all this, I was finally able to get isotope to work. I still have some things to fix so that I can get it to work exactly how I want it but as far as getting it to function properly, this is what worked for me.